# sending email in from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to add this to my email body and i want it to look like this but it doesnt work.

```
Tour: lotour.text 
Date: loddate.text
Party: lolnumparty.text 
 first name: locfname.text 
 last name: loclname.text
```

as you see i want them right after another and it doesnt work when i use a `</br>`

this is my email body.

```
objEmail.Body = "There was a booking rquest made by " & Request.QueryString("comp") & " to see more details click the link " + x
```

this is my full code

```
 If Page.IsValid And ValidateCCNumber(cardnumber.Text) = True Then
            SqlDataSource1.Insert()
            Dim x As String
            x = "http://www.clubabc.com/bookingrequest/confirm.aspx?date=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(now.Text) & "&tfname=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p1fname.Text) & "&tlname=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p1lname.Text) & "&comp=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("comp") & "&land=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(land.Text))
            Dim objEmail As New MailMessage()
            objEmail.To = "cnna@BC.com"
            objEmail.From = "page@bc.com"
            objEmail.Cc = memail.Text
            objEmail.Subject = "Booking for " + p1fname.Text + " " + p1lname.Text + " made by " & Request.QueryString("comp")
            objEmail.Body = "There was a booking rquest made by " & Request.QueryString("comp") & " to see more details click the link " + x
            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.bc.com"
            Try
                SmtpMail.Send(objEmail)
            Catch exc As Exception
                Response.Write("Send failure: " + exc.ToString())
            End Try
            Response.Redirect("http://www.clubabc.com/bookingrequest/confirm.aspx?date=" + now.Text + "&tfname=" + p1fname.Text + "&tlname=" + p1lname.Text + "&comp=" + Request.QueryString("comp") & "&land=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(land.Text))
        ElseIf ValidateCCNumber(cardnumber.Text) = False Then
            invalidcard.Visible = True
        End If
```

Comment: if you do make it an HTML email you want <br /> not </br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are searching for ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)):

```
Environment.NewLine
```

The `<br>` tag will only work in HTML Emails.

**Update**

This would be a very [simple example](http://ideone.com/clone/HpdZg), how you could use `Environment.NewLine`:

```
Imports System

Class Sample
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim firstName As String = "John"
      Dim lastName As String = "Doe"
      Dim city As String = "Brooklyn"

      Console.WriteLine("First name: " + firstName + Environment.NewLine + "Last name: " + lastName + Environment.NewLine + "City: " + city + Environment.NewLine)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem? `"Your text" + Environment.NewLine` or `"Your text\r\n"`

Comment: how would i use it i tryed something like objEmail.Body =  "Name:" & fname.text + environment.newline & "address:" address.text + environment.newline.....

Comment: `objEmail.Body = "Name:" + fname.text + Environment.NewLine + "address:" + address.text + Environment.NewLine ... `

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Have a look here for a very simple example: http://ideone.com/HpdZg

Answer (score 0):

Try to set IsHtml property for objEmail variable to get some more formatting possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Enviornment.NewLine, instead use vbCrLf

Environment.NewLine may only output Cr or Lf, which may cause your email to either:

a)Be blocked because it's not RFC complient
or
b)Be marked as spammy

To have new lines in email, always use CrLf.

--Dave

Comment: -1 This is not right. Environment.NewLine is a string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Comment: Thanks! You just made my point. Always use CrLf instead of Environment.NewLine